# I need to create a number of very similar classes in Django, what's the DRYest way to do that?

Tags: python, django

I need to create several ModelAdmin and ModelForm classes in Django that all need to look like this:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Category
        exclude = ['slug']


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryForm
```

They also need to inherit from this class, or have a way to call into this class:

```
class Slugify(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_sluggable_field(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.title)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.category)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.tag)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        field = self.get_sluggable_field(obj)
        if not obj.slug:
            obj.slug = obj.to_slug(field)
        else:
            self.to_slug(obj.slug)
        obj.save()
```

The only thing different about the classes is the `model` from the `Meta` subclass. How do I do this with the little to no copy and paste? (I'm assuming there's some meta-programming involved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define a ModelForm for each ModelAdmin. You can use the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) option and use a common ModelAdmin class.

```
SlugifyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ['slug']

    def get_sluggable_field(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.title)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.category)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.tag)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        field = self.get_sluggable_field(obj)
        if not obj.slug:
            obj.slug = obj.to_slug(field)
        else:
            self.to_slug(obj.slug)
        obj.save()

admin.register(Model1, SlugifyAdmin)
admin.register(Model2, SlugifyAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that is changing is the `Meta` class, can't you inherit from `Slugify` like this?

```
class Slugify(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_sluggable_field(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.title)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.category)
        except AttributeError:
            return obj.to_slug(obj.tag)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        field = self.get_sluggable_field(obj)
        if not obj.slug:
            obj.slug = obj.to_slug(field)
        else:
            self.to_slug(obj.slug)
        obj.save()


Class MyOtherClass(Slugify):

    call Meta:
        abstract = False
        other_changes = "12345"
```

Simply inherit and override what you need to change. Good luck!

Comment: That might solve the problem of inheriting from Slugify, but that still leaves me creating essentially the same pair of classes for 5 models. Is there a way to avoid that duplication?

Comment: It also breaks the semantics of class inheritance. Done that way, you say `MyOtherClass` is a kind of `Slugify`, which does not really make sense. A mixin would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @spectras How would you go about solving this problem? Obviously I want to avoid copy-pasta, so if you have a way to create the same pair of classes for 5 models without much duplication of code that would be great.

Comment: Ah, I mis-parsed what you were asking. Yes, a mixin is the way to go.